# Very slow connection to wsdl web service

Tags: performance, wsdl, jax-ws

I am new to Java programming. i have a web client that consumes wsdl service and i could get the connection established successfully. I could even get the response from the web service, but the problem is it takes around 1 minutes  - 3 minutes to get connected. i used wsimport to generate all the client stubs. Can someone help me to improve the performance of my web client? All the client stubs are generated by below version of JAX-WS

/**
 * This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI.
 * JAX-WS RI 2.2.4-b01
 * Generated source version: 2.2
 * 
 */

Code:

```
        ChangeRequestServices service = new ChangeRequestServices(); - Huge delay in executing this line.

        port = service.getDefaultEndpoint(); - This actually does the getPort()

        ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,"<endpoint url>" );
        ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY,"<username>" );
        ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY,"<password>" );
        ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.SESSION_MAINTAIN_PROPERTY, true);
```

Thanks in advance.